# Is there a way to purchase Cydia apps from a regular browser and not from inside Cydia?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a way to purchase Cydia apps from a regular browser and not from inside Cydia?

Comment: Basically bumping this question since it still doesn't have a valid answer yet and I am looking for the same. Didn't want to create a new (duplicate) question unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. [The home page](http://cydia.saurik.com/)

Comment: This is cool, never gone there on desktop before! But this is far from answering the question. :P

Comment: do you mean to purchase them on your mac or do you mean loking at the store without being on their website?

Comment: The question is just about purchasing... And Cydia apps go well beyond saurik thanks to being able to add different sources. :)

Comment: This link doesn't allow even browsing the apps, not to mention buying them. The idea is to avoid entering sensitive paypal/amazon credentials inside cydia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can purchase from Cydia on any website, but there are websites which allow you to view the packages available from Cycia, such as [Cydia Search](http://planet-iphones.com/cydia/). You can use these sites to determine what you want to download on your computer so that you only have to do the actual downloads from your iPhone. If you look enough, you can find some applications that you can download using your computer, but they do not come through Cydia.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Cydia source is hosted and not actually in-app, @luca590's link is most appropriate right now for access to the store.

Otherwise, when [Lima](http://infini-dev.com/) releases, it'll be a different ballgame.